# HTML/CSS - Two divs with single gradient background but one sticky element

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a problem which is frustrating me somewhat. The scenario is:

I have two divs. Top div is a banner (containing logo only). Bottom div is the navbar, containing some icons as links and a dropdown.

I want the two following things:

1. have a consistent linear gradient background over the two divs
2. the bottom, navbar div to have position:sticky, top:0, so that it
   remains at the top of the page when scrolling.

I can achieve both of the above independently, but not concurrently. Is there anyway to achieve this?

A simplified version of the CSS and HTML, with the version that has the sticky navbar, but the gradient is per div, not starting in one div and finishing in the other:

```css
#banner,
.navbar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(0, 87, 128), rgb(0, 157, 230));
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

.container {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner" class="Container-fluid">
  <div class="banner-row">
    <h1>Logo!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/home/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/"><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <p>Stuff to fill a space.</p>
</div>
```

And with the opposite:

```css
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(0, 87, 128), rgb(0, 157, 230));
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

.container {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="banner" class="Container-fluid">
    <div class="banner-row">
      <h1>Logo!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/home/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/about/"><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact/"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container body-content">
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <p>Stuff to fill a space.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider a pseudo-element within the navbar where you apply the gradient coloration and you overflow it from the top so it cover the banner. You simply need to adjust the top value depending on your styles.

```css
#banner {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:-100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(0, 87, 128), rgb(0, 157, 230));
}


.navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

.container {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner" class="Container-fluid">
  <div class="banner-row">
    <h1>Logo!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/home/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/"><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <p>Stuff to fill a space.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Temani, thank you taking the time to respond, I have added this to my .css for my site but it isn't applying. I'm not sure why and I'm not sure what to show/tell you to aid in troubleshooting, my apologies.

Comment: @Ubi did you clear your cache? you have probably more CSS involved? can you share a link to a full code

Comment: If you mean a link to the site, I don't think it will be available as it's currently under development on a VPN for my workplace. For a similar reason, I'm not sure I'm allowed to freely share code with you. If it helps, we are using bootstrap.css (bootstrap v3.0.0) with site.css being where we add rules to go on top of that

Comment: @Ubi you shared a simplified CSS and you are for sure using a more complex CSS including Bootstrap so my solution will remain the same but the CSS may need to be adjusted to go with your code ... If I am not able to see the code, it's difficult for me to help.

Comment: @Ubi add `display:block` to the pseudo element and make the z-index of the banner bigger `z-index: 2000;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182267/discussion-between-ubi-and-temani-afif).